# How to create a formulae field to increase the count

Tags: formula-field

I have a requirement where I want to capture the count based upon no. of times a field is updated eg. if there is a checkbox named as Speeding and if I clicked the field Speeding thrice, I should capture this count as 3 on another field.

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried. Surely you can figure out how to get started at least? If you're not sure where to begin, look at trailhead.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot capture the number of clicks from a formula field. Formula fields operate on the database values not user interface.

if you need to capture clicks, etc you will need to write a custom VF page to handle your business.

If you are trying to count the updates, you will need to use a workflow rule that fires when the field is changed and increments the value of another field. Again, not possible by a formula as it would be redundant.

Comment: But you could capture number of times it  gets updated, which I think is the question here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson  confused by your comment - For a field you can use a wfr to increment a field if another field was changed. Even in my answer??

Comment: Ah somehow missed your last paragraph.